# How do I apply different changes to each control when selecting by class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a series of checkboxes with the same class. I want to get all the checkboxes with that same class as a collection and extract their id and checked status. But all the select by class examples I've seen just apply a single change to all elements of that class. I need to get a collection/array of all the checkbox elements with that class so I can iterate over them.

Ok, I've tried some of the suggestions and had no luck.
This throws an Object Expected error in IE8:

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox'].chkRoles");
```

And this gives me an empty array every time, regardless of what's checked.

```
    var mandatoryRoleIDs = [];

    $('input.chkRoles[type="checkbox"]').each(function (i, checkbox)
    {
        if ($(checkbox).attr('checked'))
            mandatoryRoleIDs.push($(checkbox).attr('id'));
    });
```

Comment: [Read the docs!](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('classname');
```

Then iterate over it to do what you need.

```
for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    var current = checkboxes[i];
    // stuff on current
}
```

Using jQuery is not necessary in this simple case, and `querySelectorAll` is not totally supported by older browser; Vanilla JS is the best way to do it!

Since you need to support IE8(damn Microsoft) you should do something like this:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    className = "classname";
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var current = inputs[i];
    if (current.type !== 'checkbox' || current.className.indexOf(className) === -1) continue;
    //do stuff with current
}
```

See a [working JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/n6L3q/) of this snippet.

Comment: and what if not only checkboxes has specific `classname` ?

Comment: "I've got a series of checkboxes with the **same class**. I want to get all the checkboxes with that **same class**" -- is it specified that that class is set in other elements which are not checkboxes?

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work since this app will only run on IE8 and it doesn't support getElementsByClassName

Comment: @Legion For IE8 you can use `document.querySelectorAll('.classname')` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Since your question is tagged with jQuery, here's how you can do it with jQuery's each() function:

```
$('input.someClass[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i,el){
    var $this = $(el),
        id = $this.attr('id'),
        checked = $this.attr('checked');
    /* do stuff with id and checked */
});
```

Comment: Am I reading this correctly? function(i,el)? not function(id, el)?

Comment: the first argument passed to the function is the index, the second is the element. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: @Legion it doesn't matter what you call them. as nderscore said, the first argument will always be index, and second will be element -- regardless of their variables' names.